# Owl Carousel 2 - слайдер не реагирует на переключение

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, slider, owl-carousel

Установил слайдер от owl на laravel 7.
Подключил все скачав source файлы.
На сайте сейчас добавлено три слайда, над самим слайдером выводятся кнопки-переключашки с именами каждого слайда

Добавил код который предлагает разработчик для кнопок таким образом

```
@foreach ($sliders as $slider)
  <a class="mr-1 mb-2 mt-3 badge badge-yellow" href="#{{ $slider->id }}">{{ $slider->sl_name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

На данном этапе я получаю id слайда (из базы) и получаю его имя.
В сам слайдер я добавил вот этот код :

```
<div class="slider-item" data-hash="{{ $slider->id }}">
```

Таким образом я привязываю к слайдеру свой ID из таблицы.
После запуска сервера для проверки на работоспособность, у меня возникает ошибка в том что я могу переключится только на третий слайдер, а не предыдущие два я не могу переключится, хотя в адресной строке прописывается ссылка до слайда. В скрипте я указывал данные как в документации

```
items: 1,
loop: false,
dots: true,
autoplay: true,
URLhashListener:true,
startPosition: 'URLHash',
```

Но не чего не работает кроме последнего добавленного слайда

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить id к элементам слайдера и в URLHash передавать id элемента, который должен показываться первым

Comment: Добавил, сейчас выглядит это вот так
`<div class="single-slider-item" id="{{ $slider->id }}" data-hash="{{ $slider->id }}">`
А куда добавить URLhash ? В скрипт выполняющийся ?